# Android OpenCV FaceDetection - System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am new in OpenCV and i have troubles with OpenCv,when i want to use it with Android.I have read the questions already asked but i did not found a solution.

Here is my problem : 
I want to simply create a FaceDetector class,which will detect faces from a given bitmap.Have somebody a sample source-code for facedetection from Bitmap (JavaCV or OpenCV)?

> System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); works without Android but in android project does not work.

```
public class FaceDetector {

    private static Bitmap bitmap=null;
    public FaceDetector (Bitmap bm){
        this.bitmap=bm;
    }

    public boolean isFaceDetected() {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new    CascadeClassifier("/res/raw/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");

        Mat image=null;
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, image);

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        return faceDetections.toArray().length>0;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at [opencv-java-tutorials](http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/06-face-detection-and-tracking.html)